# Get 10 access using Microsoft access

Tags: ms-access

I have a project for library management in which on report generation section. I want to show all issue book list So i want show only 10 records on each page . I tried get records using limit clause but limit does not support in access. 
So any one can help me to access 10 records on each turn

Comment: SELECT TOP ... be aware that MS Access will also give any matches, so you may end up with more than 10 records unless you ORDER BY both the relevant column and a unique column.

Comment: Thanks for your reply But i want to show only 30 records on each page of print preview control in vb.net . if i have more than 30 records then how can show remaining records on next page